# Spring + Atmosphere + Tomcat thread leak

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7, atmosphere

i'm facing a strange problem with atmosphere and can't figure how to fix it.
I'm trying to implement server push notifications. Notofications should be broadcasted to all connected clients (up to 10, it's an intranet webapp) witch are ANDROID 4.2 browsers.

Notifications is working well, and all stuff are being pushed, but atmosphere creates an high number of tomcat threads, ending in a thread leak after about 3-4k page requests.
Tomcat 7.0.40 if configured with NIO connector, with 150 max threads and 60000 of timeout

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- SECURITY -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- char encoding -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> 

    <!-- Declare a DispatcherServlet as usual -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.MeteorServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.servlet</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.asyncSupport</param-name>
            <param-value>org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7BIOSupportWithWebSocket</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache</param-value>
       </init-param>
<!--       <init-param> -->
<!--            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.sessionSupport</param-name> -->
<!--            <param-value>true</param-value> -->
<!--        </init-param> -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.resumeOnBroadcast</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.shareableThreadPool</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.maxProcessingThreads</param-name>
            <param-value>20</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.maxAsyncWriteThreads</param-name>
            <param-value>20</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.useNative</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
<!--         <init-param> -->
<!--            <param-name>org.atmosphere.useBlocking</param-name> -->
<!--            <param-value>false</param-value> -->
<!--        </init-param> -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.useStream</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor</param-name>
            <param-value>org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor.heartbeatFrequencyInSeconds</param-name>
            <param-value>60</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterLifeCyclePolicy</param-name>
          <param-value>EMPTY_DESTROY</param-value>
      </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <display-name>cielo-cp</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <session-config>
      <session-timeout>1440</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/accessDenied</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Spring MVC Controller:

```
@Controller
public class PushController extends AbstractController{

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/push")
    public void pushAsync(AtmosphereResource atmosphereResource){
        AtmosphereUtils.suspend(atmosphereResource);
    }

}
```

BroadcasterService:

```
@Service
public class BroadcasterService {

    @Autowired
    private PushNotificationService service;

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


    public void receiveMessage(@Observes PushEvent e) {
        List<PushableMessage> messages = service.pollMessages(e.getType());
        try {
            Broadcaster b = AtmosphereUtils.lookupBroadcaster(false);       
            try {   
                b.broadcast(mapper.writeValueAsString(messages));

            } catch(Exception ex){
                logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
        } catch (Throwable t){
            logger.debug(t.getMessage(), t);
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
@Service
public class PushNotificationService {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PushNotificationService.class);

    @Autowired
    private Event<PushEvent> event;


    public List<PushableMessage> pollMessages(TipologiaPush key) {
            ....
        return result;
    }


    public void pushMessage(PushableMessage message){
        ...
        queue.put(message);
        event.fire(message.getEvent());
    }
```

}

and utils:

```
public final class AtmosphereUtils {

    public static AtmosphereResource getAtmosphereResource(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return getMeteor(request).getAtmosphereResource();
    }

    public static Meteor getMeteor(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return Meteor.build(request);
    }

    public static void suspend(final AtmosphereResource resource) {

        final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        resource.addEventListener(new AtmosphereResourceEventListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onSuspend(AtmosphereResourceEvent event) {
                countDownLatch.countDown();
                logger.debug("Suspending Client..." + resource.uuid() + " with transport " + resource.transport());
                resource.removeEventListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnect(AtmosphereResourceEvent event) {
                logger.debug("Disconnecting Client..." + resource.uuid());
                super.onDisconnect(event);
            }    
        });

        if (AtmosphereResource.TRANSPORT.LONG_POLLING.equals(resource.transport())) {
            resource.resumeOnBroadcast(true).suspend();
        } else {
            resource.suspend();
        }

        try {
            countDownLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Interrupted while trying to suspend resource {}", resource);
        }

        AtmosphereUtils.lookupBroadcaster(true).addAtmosphereResource(resource);
    }

    public static Broadcaster lookupBroadcaster(boolean create) {
        Broadcaster b = BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup("/*", create);
        return b;
    }

}
```

other service call: notificationService.pushMessage(....);
the javascript part is:

```
var socket = $.atmosphere;

function handleAtmosphere(url, handleResult) {

    var request = new $.atmosphere.AtmosphereRequest();
    request.transport = "websocket"; // "streaming is even worse";
    request.url = url;
    request.contentType = "application/json";
    request.fallbackTransport = "long-polling"; //for android 4.2, default browser don't support websocket

    request.onMessage = function(response){
        ....
    };


    var subSocket = socket.subscribe(request);

}
```

that being said, i've tried many configurations, but still some threads stay active.
I'm using Spring 3.2.5, SpringSec 3.2 RC2 and Atmosphere 2.0.4

Comment: Please post snippets and not all your scripts, the chance of your problem being solved will increase if you do.

Comment: I have no experience with atmosphere. That said, one reason for high number of threads could be that the threads are not released back. And if someone is holding them back even after serving the requests, then it's that code/config i'd be checking. I couldn't go through all that code you've provided, but i'd check if you're handling/managing any threads or any of atmosphere threads, please check them first.

Comment: ok i've removed irrelevant code.

Comment: @prabugp you're right, the threads seems not being released. I'm trying to figure out why, and this is what i'm asking :). If i remove atmosphere calls, threads are released normally without any leak

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/issues/717

Couple of things to note from that thread:
With shareable thread pool, you must shut down the associated executor yourself. That's a framework limitation. But why BroadcastConfig are getting stopped and not AsyncWrite needs investigation

And

The thread running are associated with the ExecutorServices. It's the ExecutorService to decide when to kill those threads, not Atmosphere. Since you are using the CachedThreadPool, this is kind of expected. I've tested with Tomcat 7.0.27, shared thread pool and NIO connector. If you use the BIO Connector EMPTY_DESTROY will not work because the disconnection will not be detected.

So my recommendation for you is to use a bounded thread pool so you don't end up with too many thread running.

See if this is what you're facing.

Comment: Also, please share a thread dump to see where Threads are blocked.

Comment: isn't that thread related with 1.x version? i'm using 2.0.4, i thought it was fixed. I'll try to get a thread dump (never done)

Comment: It seems that Atmosphere-Shared-DispatchOp and Atmosphere-Shared-AsyncOp are correctly bounded, the threads leaking are all of **http-nio-8080-exec** type

Comment: @jfarcand here a thread dump: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mB-5qyEKAvfOF-we8w72JJzI36cZR97Xa2kM53UZc7Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You aren't using Tomcat NIO, hence you can see BlockingIOCometSupport in your log. Google how to install Tomcat NIO :-)

Comment: @jfarcand sorry for late reply. My tomcat server.xml has: `<Connector acceptorThreadCount="2" connectionTimeout="60000" maxThreads="250" 
        port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
        redirectPort="8443" socket.directBuffer="false"/>` ins't that correct?

Comment: and when tomcat starts i have: `INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
gen 14, 2014 6:03:06 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector`